# Limit Firebase Google OAuth Authentication to specific users

Tags: oauth-2.0, firebase, google-authentication

I'm using Firebase to handle my Google OAuth login for my website. Does anyone knew how to restrict the users who have access to the application? For example, I only want x@gmail.com, y@gmail.com, and z@gmail.com to successfully be able to log in via google to my application.

I wasn't sure if this was a Firebase or Google question, but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I dont know if I'm wrong, But isn't it possible to create allowed_email_list on your db and check if the entered email exists in that and then only allow login.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firebase's authentication handles only that: the *authentication* of users through any of the mechanisms you enable. Whether those users have access to your data is called *authorization* and it is handled through the security rules of your Firebase.

So:

- Authentication allows the user to identify him/herself with your application. See [Firebase's documentation on authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html) (for JavaScript/Web, but it exists for all supported platforms).
- Authorization limits read/write access to your data to specific users, based on their authentication. See [Firebase's documentation on its security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/).

Limiting access to your data to specific email addresses is certainly possible. I recommend that you read [Firebase's documentation on its security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/) and try to make it work based on that. If you have any problems, post what you've tried and we'll be able to help you better.

Answer (score 9):

These rules will allow anybody to login, but only the listed email addresses to read or write data:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read":  "auth.email == 'x@gmail.com' || 
               auth.email == 'y@gmail.com' || 
               auth.email == 'z@gmail.com'",

    ".write": "auth.email == 'x@gmail.com' || 
               auth.email == 'y@gmail.com' || 
               auth.email == 'z@gmail.com'"
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, but would like to block login completely. In other words, they can go through Google Authentication, but it says you are not authorized on this page, or something. Would that use .validate somehow? Otherwise, it seems that folks can login, but they can't read/write, which is ok, but I would rather have them not login at all.

Comment: @CodeFinity see [FrankVanPuffelen's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28422909/80428) about the difference between authentication vs authorisation, Firebase handle the former