# How can I restrict google login to my company's email domain (@company.com) in React Native?

Tags: android, email, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

## Question

What is the best way to prevent users from using an email address that does not end in @mycompany.com from logging in to our internal app through Firebase/Google auth?

## Goal

- Prevent users from using the wrong email to login to the app
- Fetch the user's company email address and use that for authentication elsewhere (i.e. for pulling data from an internal website)

## Restraints

- I am using react-native init because I had to implement with our company's native SDK module
- Preferably would like a solution with Firebase since we are already using it with said native SDK module for FCM/push notifications.

## Research results

- I saw that react-native-google-signin had a "hostedDomain" option, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I'm not sure how to use it, and there are no docs or good examples of its use. There was a feature request for it [here](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin/issues/199) but that's all I can find.
- I saw that there is a similar repo, react-native-google-sign-in, but it doesn't offer any more information on this subject.
- I read somewhere that I'm probably thinking about this all wrong and authentication can't restrict email addresses(?), but I can restrict who can access information with said email addresses. This doesn't help me because we're not using Firebase's database for anything right now. I need a way to guide users to log in using their company email.
- [This person seemed to have a similar issue](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2/issues/13) and found a solution for passport, but I don't know how to apply this to my use case.

## Setup

- IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.2.2
- React Native 0.47.1 (using react-native init, not CRNA or expo since I needed to integrate with a native SDK module)
- google-services.json from Firebase exists in android/app folder

#### Android Setup

package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.0", /* Ignore this */
    "firebase": "^4.2.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.47.1",
    "react-native-app-intro": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.12"
}
```

android/settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = '[My Project Name]'
include ':react-native-google-signin'
project(':react-native-google-signin').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-google-signin/android')
include ':react-native-linear-gradient'
project(':react-native-linear-gradient').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android')

include ':app', ':[Internal Android SDK]'
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.1"
}

subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate{
        if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

[...]

dependencies {
    compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
    }
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':[Internal Android SDK]')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}

[...]

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

#### React Native setup

Current folder structure:

```
> app
    > components [...]
    > config [...]
    > screens
        HomeScreen.js
        LoginScreen.js
        [...]
    > styles [...]
    router.js (just a simple StackNavigator setup from react-navigation)
> assets
    > fonts [...]
    > img [...]
> node_modules [...]
index.android.js
index.ios.js
package.json
[...]
```

LoginScreen.js (This is a work in progress)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, Button, Image, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {GoogleSignin, GoogleSigninButton} from 'react-native-google-signin';

export default class LoginScreen extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._setupGoogleSignin().then(() => console.log('Mounted & Google setup complete.'));
    }

    async _setupGoogleSignin() {
        try {
            await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ autoResolve: true });
            await GoogleSignin.configure({
                hostedDomain: 'mycompany.com' //doesn't do anything
            });

            const user = await GoogleSignin.currentUserAsync();
            console.log('User: ',user);
            this.setState({user});
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log("Play services error", err.code, err.message);
        }
    }

    _signIn() {
        GoogleSignin.signIn()
            .then((user) => {
                console.log('User: ',user);
                this.setState({user: user});
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('WRONG SIGNIN', err);
            })
            .done();
    }

    _signOut() {
        GoogleSignin.revokeAccess().then(() => GoogleSignin.signOut()).then(() => {
                this.setState({user: null});
            })
            .done();
    }

    render(){

        if (!this.state.user){
            return (
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <View style={{flex: 1.5, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 40}}>
                        <Image
                            style={{width: 156, height: 156, resizeMode: 'contain'}}
                            source={require('../../assets/img/google_logo1600.png')} />
                        <Text style={{fontSize: 32, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
                            Google Identity
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={[{fontSize: 15, paddingTop: 5}]}>
                            To continue, please sign-in.
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', marginBottom: 40}}>
                        <GoogleSigninButton
                            style={{width: 312, height: 48}}
                            size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
                            color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Light}
                            onPress={() => this._signIn()}/>
                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <View style={{flex: 1.5, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 40}}>
                        <Image
                            style={{width: 156, height: 156, resizeMode: 'contain'}}
                            source={require('../../assets/img/google_logo1600.png')} />
                        <Text style={{fontSize: 32, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
                            Google Identity
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={[{fontSize: 15, paddingTop: 5}]}>
                            To continue, please sign-in.
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', marginBottom: 40}}>
                        <Button style={{width: 312, height: 48, backgroundColor: '#4385F2', color: 'white'}} title="Log Out" onPress={() => this._signOut()} />
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
        }

    }
}
```

If there's a better way to do this, I'm all ears. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46163832/6448362 look at this answer. with the 'hd; parameter i was able to restrict the domains for the login

Comment: I think this is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614476/restrict-firebase-authentication-to-a-certain-domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to limit who can authenticate with the default Firebase Authentication Google provider. But all the user does by signing in is authenticating themselves: "I am Frank van Puffelen and here's the proof".

You can restrict what resources users have access to. For example for the [Firebase Database you can use its server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) to determine what each user is authorized to access. Here you can [limit access to users from a specific domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943350/how-do-i-lock-down-firebase-database-to-any-user-from-a-specific-email-domain).

Also see:

- [Limit Firebase Google OAuth Authentication to specific users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421906/limit-firebase-google-oauth-authentication-to-specific-users)
- [How to disable Signup in Firebase 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357554/how-to-disable-signup-in-firebase-3-x)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So in my Research bullet point #3 I mentioned that we aren't using the Firebase database for anything right now, so I'm not sure restricting users' access to it is going to help me.

If it's not possible, what do you recommend for restricting emails that can login like colleges do (requiring a .edu account for example)? Would it be possible through Firebase Email/Password auth? Or is the only option to do a manual check myself? That seems rather sloppy though.

Also, any idea what the hostedDomain option is supposed to do then? 

Thanks!

Comment: Any idea what this method "setHostedDomain" does?
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions.Builder#setHostedDomain(java.lang.String).

Comment: What backend service do you want to protect?

Comment: Our internal Wordpress website that the app connects to in order to pull data (such as posts) from. I mainly just need their company email credentials before authenticating with our website's node server to tell us who they are. Then we can personalize information relevant to their accounts within our internal website. The user database is on our Wordpress SQL database. Does that help?

Comment: If you're trying to restrict access of your own backend to users from a specific domain, [pass the JWT from the client to the server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients), [decode and verify it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library) and then authorize/restrict access based on the information from the JWT and your use-case. That's essentially what all Firebase's backend services also do.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense, I believe I understand what needs to be done now, thank you! Last question then is what is that hostedDomain option from react-native-google-signin (that implements the setHostedDomain method)? Is that something else entirely?