# Restrict Firebase authentication to a certain domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I want to restrict the Firebase Authentication only  by ne mail domain name, to make this mail access to my application :

exemple@exemple.fr

I did this in the database side of firebase

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.token.email.endsWith('@exemple.fr')",
    ".write": "auth.token.email.endsWith('@exemple.fr')"
  }
}
```

I think i'm doing something wrong, thank you for your help.

Comment: You show "exemple@exemple.com" as your example, but your rules are showing "@exemple.fr".  ".com" != ".fr"

Comment: Sorry I, misspelled it on the post, not working anyway .

Comment: I want to do a rules to an email

Comment: I'm not sure why your rules don't work. But I'm quite certain the rules in my answer here work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943350/how-do-i-lock-down-firebase-database-to-any-user-from-a-specific-email-domain

Comment: I sort of want to do the same thing but I was more looking for a way to restrict other domains from signing up because that seems to make more sense to me. So I'm looking into firebase functions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.token.email.matches(/.*@exemple.fr$/)",
    ".write": "auth.token.email.matches(/.*@exemple.fr$/)"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me and I am able to restrict logged in Google user to my org domain

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.email.matches('.*@domain[.]com');
    }
  }
}
```